# C++ How to get arraysize from dynamic allocation?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, size, dynamic-allocation

I declared `int star = new int;` and I put values in `star`. Something like:

```
int *star = new int;
int i,j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if(words[i] == '*')
    {
        star[j] = i;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Now I want to know about `star`'s size. I tried `sizeof()` and `_msize()` but they don't work, they just read the type's size.

Comment: Paste the code here, not an image.

Comment: `star` isn't an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`star` is a pointer that points to a single integer. So the `length` should be  1, up to you to set it. `star[0]` is ok, but `star[1]` would be out of bounds.  By the way, when you use dynamic allocation, don't forget to `delete star;` at the end.

`sizeof(star)` will give you the size of the pointer, and not to the number of elements that were allocated.

If you want to know the dynamic size, you have to keep track of it by yourself:

```
size_t length = 15;           // or any number you want
int *star = new int[length];  // this time you've allocated an array
...
delete[] star;                // if you allocate an array, don't forget the []
```

An alternative is to use `vector<int>` which are fully dynamic, can grow as needed,  and take care of deallocation when they are no longer needed:

```
 vector<int> star;  // empty vector created
  ...
      star.push_back(i); // add an element
  ...
  j=star.size();    // in fact you don't need j anymore
```

You can access members exactly as with arrays ( e.g. `star[k])`

Comment: Nobody knows that how long the length is. If inputs are 3 then size is 3. That's what I want like malloc in C. I want to make that function, then do I use vector ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared star as an array, rather as a single integer. If the point of this is to find out how many times '*' shows up in your file, you should create an integer `int count = 0` and perform `count++;` every time `word[i] == '*'`.

Comment: then What kind of fuction do I use? I want to have same effect like malloc in C.

Comment: I did like that. I want to know how to use dynamic allocation.